# Attachments in CSRListform are not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-side-rendering

`I am using CSRListForm in a list (new list item). The columns work fine but the attachments are not working.

When I click on the attachments icon, I get the error "span with id part1 does not exist".

Can you please share some sample CSR implementation that uses attachments in the new form as well as edit form.

Thanks in advance.
[image: Screen Shot for your reference]

Comment: can you share with us the code you are using ?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/35499c32-777b-4080-bd31-e49a12e54694/attachments-in-csrlistform-are-not-working?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious